# How to make pull request?

Tags: github

I am new in git and in nodejs. My question is I build a project and uploaded it on github in main branch. But members are asking to to give pull request. How can I make a pull request please tell me full procedure with commands if possible thankyou.
I uploaded on git like this

```
Git init
Git add . 
Git commit -m"initial commit"
Git git add origin main githublink(ssh)
Git push -u origin main
```

After this my project is uploaded successfully
Now how can I make a pull request

Comment: Make your own branch from main, commit your changes there, and then create a pull request from your branch to main.

Comment: Note that pull requests are a GitHub thing, not a Git thing. (There are also pull requests on Bitbucket, but they're a tiny bit different. GitLab has "merge requests" rather than "pull requests", which are the same idea yet again, but yet again, slightly different. In any case "plain" Git lacks PRs; all the details are specific to the hosting site.)

Answer (score 2):

- first you need to checkout from the main branch by git checkout
- then you develop and code in that branch
- next you commit and push that branch on github repo

```
    git commit -m"initial commit"
    git add origin <your_branch> githublink(ssh)
    git push -u origin <your_branch>
```

- finally you access the github page and your new branch. create a pull request into the main branch. then share that pr to your colleagues.

for example the last step:
[image]